# Changing reference to an outer function

Tags: python, scope, metaprogramming

```py
def foo():
    print(True)


def bar():
    foo()


def baz():
    def foo():
        print(False)

    foo()
    bar()


baz()
```

Outputs:

```py
False
True
```

I need to make it output:

```py
False
False
```

By making `bar` call `foo` defined inside of `baz` without touching anything outside of `baz` itself.

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: @forgetso, testing. I need to mock bar's global dependency on foo.

Comment: Ah - You can [monkeypatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/monkeypatch.html) in pytest

Comment: Python *does not have dynamic scoping*, python has *lexical scope*. Almost certainly, you should use an alternative approach

Comment: @GlebKisenkov consider the [built-in mocking lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this, you need to overwrite `foo`'s definition in the global scope. Just use the `global` keywbord:

```
def foo():
    print(True)

def bar():
    foo()

def baz():
    global foo

    old_foo = foo # if you want to backup the original definition of foo (optional)

    def foo():
        print(False)

    foo()
    bar()

    foo = old_foo # revert foo to its original state (optional)

    baz()
```

Output:

```
False
False
```